# Read online PDF file using MuPDF

Tags: java, android, pdf, mupdf

I have two issues 
1) Annotation not work
2) I want read online pdf document

I build MuPDF using this link
http://mupdf.com/doc/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android

1) I get project mupdf/platform/android
I run that default app annotation working fine but i create that project to library file they asking want to save but annotation not save.

2)  It will read local file but i want read online file also.  my android code

```
pdf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pdf);
    onPdf = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.onPdf);

    pdf.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(path);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MuPDFActivity.class);

            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            intent.setData(uri);

            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });

    onPdf.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(netPath);


            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MuPDFActivity.class);

            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

            intent.setData(uri);

            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Modified MuPDFActivity - I change all file are open openBuffer method

```
private MuPDFCore openBuffer(byte buffer[]) {
    System.out.println("Trying to open byte buffer");
    try {
        String magic = "";
        core = new MuPDFCore(this, buffer, magic);
        // New file: drop the old outline data
        OutlineActivityData.set(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
    return core;
}
```

My mainfest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".PdfTestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.artifex.mupdfdemo.OutlineActivity"
        android:label="@string/outline_title"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.artifex.mupdfdemo.PrintDialogActivity"
        android:label="@string/print"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

My stacktrace

```
12-25 19:02:41.544: E/TAG(22925): /sample.pdf:     open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-25 19:02:41.544: E/tag(22925): file
12-25 19:02:41.546: I/System.out(22925): Trying to open        /sample.pdf
 12-25 19:02:41.549: D/dalvikvm(22925): Trying to load lib    /mnt/asec/com.example.testnew-1/lib/libmupdf.so 0x41792e10
 12-25 19:02:41.576: D/dalvikvm(22925): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/com.example.testnew-1/lib/libmupdf.so 0x41792e10
 12-25 19:02:41.576: D/dalvikvm(22925): No JNI_OnLoad found in /mnt/asec/com.example.testnew-1/lib/libmupdf.so 0x41792e10, skipping init
 12-25 19:02:41.577: I/libmupdf(22925): Opening document...
 12-25 19:02:41.577: E/libmupdf(22925): error: cannot open /sample.pdf: No such file or directory
 12-25 19:02:41.577: E/libmupdf(22925): error: cannot load document '/sample.pdf'
 12-25 19:02:41.577: E/libmupdf(22925): error: Cannot open document: '/sample.pdf'
 12-25 19:02:41.577: E/libmupdf(22925): Failed: Cannot open document: '/sample.pdf'
 12-25 19:02:41.580: I/System.out(22925): java.lang.Exception: Cannot open file: /sample.pdf
```

Comment: Have you solve this problem ?

Comment: Try below answer I done for this model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I download PDF file and convert to Bytes and open in MuPDF Core.

Download file

```
byte buffer[] = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urls[0].openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_READ);
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        int len = inputStream.available();
        buffer = new byte[len];

        // inputStream.read(buffer, 0, len);

        while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
        Log.e("Length", "" + byteBuffer.size());
        inputStream.close();
        // and then we can return your byte array.

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        });
```

Open core

```
RelativeLayout mupdfWrapper;
MuPDFCore core;
public byte[] buffer;
mupdfWrapper = (RelativeLayout) viewRoot
                .findViewById(R.id.mupdf_wrapper);
        // Intent intent =new Intent(getActivity(),MuPDFActivity.class);
        // startActivity(intent);

        core = new MuPDFCore(getActivity(), buffer, "");
        MuPDFReaderView mDocView = new MuPDFReaderView(getActivity());
        mDocView.setAdapter(new MuPDFPageAdapter(getActivity(), core));
        mupdfWrapper.addView(mDocView, new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: can you please share full code for this as I could not get it work? thank you so much